# Unable to register in a self hosted taiga.io docker instance; redis ConnectionError 99

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, taiga

I'm trying to spin up a [taiga.io](https://www.taiga.io/) instance from https://github.com/taigaio/docker-taiga-5 but whenever I try to register, I have this error on my server:

```
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 570, in apply_async
server_1         |     **options
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 755, in send_task
server_1         |     self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 294, in on_task_call
server_1         |     self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 135, in consume_from
server_1         |     return self.start(task_id)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 114, in start
server_1         |     self._consume_from(initial_task_id)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 142, in _consume_from
server_1         |     self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2229, in subscribe
server_1         |     ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2161, in execute_command
server_1         |     self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2172, in _execute
server_1         |     connection.connect()
server_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
server_1         |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
server_1         | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Address not available.
```

There is only this line regarding celery in the `settings.py` file:

```
CELERY_ENABLED = True
```

And there is strangely no redis service in the [compose file](https://github.com/taigaio/docker-taiga-5/blob/master/docker-compose.advanced.yml).

In addition, the site is working.... to a detail: whenever I click an item to do an action, it seems to wait for ever, but if I manually refresh the page, it's like the action was done in the background. Maybe this is rtypoelated to what redis should have done if it was active?

I don't really know in what direction to search... the [README](https://github.com/taigaio/docker-taiga-5/blob/master/README.md) regarding a Docker setup doesn't seem to fully match the docker setup itself... Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(hi, core dev of Taiga)

You seems to be using version 5 of Taiga; you should use the taiga-6 repository, you can find here:

https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-docker

Comment: Amazing! I was actually watching at some recent moves in taiga's GitHub repositories, hoping the version 6 will be out very soon, and here you are with your message. The magic of the internet! I will not wait anymore to try it!